# Using NavMesh on Unity3D project, not working on a bridge? (Solved!)

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

I'm fairly new to unity, and I'm currently making a little 3D mini game. I made a terrain where I raised it, then cut out bits for a river. To get across to the other parts of land, I made makeshift bridges with cubes. However, when I bake my NavMesh, I can't get it to work for the bridges. I didn't declare them as obstacles, and I also tried clicking the bridge itself, going to Window -> AI -> Navigation directly on it to see if maybe that would do something different. It didn't LOL.[screen cap of overhead view of my terrain, note the two bridges on the right side that don't have the navmesh on them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4JgV.png)

Again, I tried attaching a NavMesh directly to the bridges, just to see maybe if that would do something, but nope. I tried researching if anyone else had this issue, but most other people just had trouble getting their agent to walk across it because of the step height/jump. I can't even get the NavMesh on there in the first place lol.

Answer (score 0):

**THIS MAY NOT BE THE ANSWER HE IS LOOKING FOR. I CANNOT COMMENT SINCE I AM NEW SO I WROTE IT AS AN ANSWER**

Maybe your bridge isn't considered a walkable item?

Try going to Window > AI > Navigation

Once in the Navigation tab, click on the bridge and select the OBJECT property in the Navigation tab.

Enable NAVIGATION STATIC and set NAVIGATION AREA to WALKABLE.

Rebuilt your Navmesh and see if this fixes it!